# What happens if I upload a new version of an object already transitioned to Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, s3

I created a bucket with versioning enabled and put 500GB of objects there.
I also set a lifecycle policy that transitions the whole bucket to S3 Glacier after 30 days and it was already executed.

Let's say I have `file1.jpg` that was already transitioned to Glacier, and I come today and upload a new version of `file1.jpg` (uploaded to standard storage).

Is this new `file1.jpg` overwriting the one in Glacier immediately? Will it do it after 30 days?
What are the implications of storage costs for this situation?

As this might happen to me from time to time, I'd like to know, as I have a use case where this might happen with a few thousand files every month or two.
I don't intend to retrieve/download the files already in Glacier, but I think some of them will get new versions and I know writing to something in Glacier is very expensive.